# Coding Sonar Rules In Java

Tags: java, sonarqube

I want to code my own Sonar rules in Java. We have a requirement of adding few security Rules in SonarQube. Before trying that, I have to first try coding basic rule. To do that I am following the below link:
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/tree/master/java-checks/src

I tried adding sample rules which are mentioned in sonar-examples which worked fine for me.

Now I tried adding already existing rule in the github
by creating new java file in the same folder.

Here I added,
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/DuplicateConditionIfElseIfCheck.java 
code in my main folder. I have also added respective java files in test folder too.

But I am getting the following error when I compile using -> mvn compile

```
C:\Sonar\sonar-examples-master\plugins\java-custom-rules>mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Java Custom Rules 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- sonar-packaging-maven-plugin:1.12.1:check-dependencies (default-check
-dependencies) @ java-custom-rules ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ java-custo
m-rules ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Sonar\sonar-examples-master\plugin
s\java-custom-rules\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ java-custom-rul
es ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. b
uild is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 9 source files to C:\Sonar\sonar-examples-master\plugins\java-c
ustom-rules\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] COMPILATION WARNING :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] /C:/Sonar/sonar-examples-master/plugins/java-custom-rules/src/main/jav
a/org/sonar/samples/java/MyJavaFileCheckRegistrar.java: C:\Sonar\sonar-examples-
master\plugins\java-custom-rules\src\main\java\org\sonar\samples\java\MyJavaFile
CheckRegistrar.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[WARNING] /C:/Sonar/sonar-examples-master/plugins/java-custom-rules/src/main/jav
a/org/sonar/samples/java/MyJavaFileCheckRegistrar.java: Recompile with -Xlint:un
checked for details.
[INFO] 2 warnings
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Sonar/sonar-examples-master/plugins/java-custom-rules/src/main/java/
org/sonar/samples/java/DuplicateConditionIfElseIfCheck.java:[50,54] cannot find
symbol
  symbol:   class Location
  location: interface org.sonar.plugins.java.api.JavaFileScannerContext
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.667 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-06T09:55:20+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/37M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.
1:compile (default-compile) on project java-custom-rules: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/Sonar/sonar-examples-master/plugins/java-custom-rules/src/main/java/
org/sonar/samples/java/DuplicateConditionIfElseIfCheck.java:[50,54] cannot find
symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Location
[ERROR] location: interface org.sonar.plugins.java.api.JavaFileScannerContext
```

Do I need to add any other jar files? 
Please help me.

Thanks in advance,
Shruthi

Comment: Please follow example of custom rules plugin : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/java-custom-rules

Comment: I have already those examples and it worked fine for me. Now I am trying to add any of the rules present in https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/tree/master/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java

Comment: If i tried adding the same code, I am getting the above error

Answer (score 1):

I found that when extending an existing plugin (like the java-plugin) the classpath of the original plugin was not included.
In order to include that classpath, you must set a basePlugin on the configuration of the sonar-packaging-maven-plugin, like this:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonar-packaging-maven-plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-packaging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.15</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
                <pluginClass>your.sonar.plugin</pluginClass>
                <pluginDescription>My SonarQube plugin</pluginDescription>
                <basePlugin>java</basePlugin>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

You can check out my SonarQube plugin at 
https://github.com/SPeeSimon/SonarQube-plugins

Answer (score 0):

Please check for these dependencies in your .m2 repo. Following is from pom.xml

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
      <artifactId>sonar-java-api</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
      <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I dont have sonar-java-api in my repository folder. How should i add it?

Comment: please try by removing `scope` in pom.xml. Ideally it should download from maven central repository. And try other commands like `mvn install` or `mvn package`.

Comment: and there is `sonar-java` project repo in github. `JavaFileScannerContext` is present there [link](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/tree/master/java-squid/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/java/api). Please include it as well or download the jar.

Comment: I have added dependency in pom.xml, and tried compiling. I am getting the same error. I have also tried `mvn install` and `mvn compiile`. I have also place the class `JavaFIleScannerContext`. But I am still getting the same error. Please help me.

Comment: Can you try it in IDE and manually adding dependencies in build path? download required jars from [maven central repo](http://search.maven.org)

Comment: Hi Baddie, Is it not possible to do it without eclipse? I am not getting the reason for the above error caused. Please help me.

Comment: @ShruthiSathyanarayana I thought IDE would be easier for you than maven. That's why, I suggested to use it. Can you try downloading every repo from sonar and then compiling everything starting from root path?